# Identification of redundant columns/variables in a classification case study

Tags: python, classification, logistic-regression

I have a Database with 13 columns(both categorical and numerical). The 13th column is a categorical variable SalStat which classifies weather the person is below 50k or above 50k. I am using Logical Regression for this case and want to know which columns (numerical and categorical) are redundant that is, dont affect SalStat, so that I can remove them. What function should I use for this purpose?

Comment: Here is a list of feature selection methods in scikit learn where you can start https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you can study the correlation between your variables and remove the ones that have high correlation since they in a way give the same amount of information to your model
you can start with something like `DataFrame.corr()` then draw a heatmap using seaborn for better visualization  `seaborn.heatmap()` or a more simple one with `plt.imshow(data.corr()) plt.colorbar();`